# cron scheduler not starting

Tags: raspbmc, cron

I have a few cron entries for root and for a regular user ,but sometimes after rebooting cron stops working completely. `pgrep cron` returns nothing.

Running `crontab -e` fixes this but I can't do that everytime I boot up the raspberry pi.
However it doesnt happen always. Is there any way of making a permanent fix for cron to run at every reboot?

I am running raspbmc and I have it connected via ethernet.Cron is enabled in the rapbc settings addon